# Adding page numbers when printing html with auto page-break

Tags: html, css

I want to print an HTML page with the page numbers on each page. My HTML consists of a table with rows of varying sizes. So I can not tell when a page-break will occur. I just used "page-break-inside: avoid;" in the row cause I don't want to break inside the row.

I tried using @page attribute but its not working.

```css
    @page {
        size: A4 portrait;
        margin: 11mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;
        counter-increment: page;

        @bottom-left {
            content: counter(page);
        }
    }

    @page:first {
        counter-reset: page 1;
    }
```

I tried using after footer or header but doesn't work either. The thead appears to print on each page but just count once. So I can't use it as counter-increment. Stays always as Page 1. The same for the footer.

My problem is where to put the counter-increment. I don't have a specific element to control the page-breaks.

HTML:

```html
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="header-space">
                    <%-- header code --%>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="content-block">
                        <p>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptTeste" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTeste_ItemDataBound">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div id="divQuestao">
                                        <%-- rows of variate sizes code --%>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="footer-space">
                    <%-- footer code --%>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```css
    @media print {
    @page {
        size: A4 portrait;
        margin: 11mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;
    }


    body {
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        counter-reset: page;
    }

    .header-space,
    .footer-space {
        height: 150px;
    }

    .footer-space::after { 
        top: 0px; position: relative;
        white-space: nowrap; 
        z-index: 20; width:100%;  margin:0 auto; text-align:center;
        counter-increment: page;
        content:"Page " counter(page);
    }       

    #divQuestao {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        padding-top: 30px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    }
```

It suppossed to be so easy to show the page number when printing! But it's not!!

Comment: It doesn't seem like any browser supports @bottom-left currently: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_page_page-margin-boxes

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet helps! This is how I handled page counter and pages count, using section HTML tag as a page :

```
<style type="text/css">
    section::after {
        content: counter(page) " / " counter(pages);
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let css = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));

        css.textContent = `section::after {counter-set: pages ${document.querySelectorAll('section').length}}`;
    });
</script>
```